# How to set absolute path to file in Ngnix config

Tags: regex, nginx, routes, single-page-application, nginx-location

I have my ngnix config.

```
location ~* ^[^.]*$ {
rewrite ^.*$ /index.html;
}
```

But if I go, for example, to `/books/book`. Then index.html in /books is returned. So, my bundle.js doesn't exist in the path `/books/bundle.js`.
How to set index.html but from the root directory?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "index.html was returned in /books"?

Comment: Yes, it was returned from path url/books/index.html. Should be from url/index.html

Comment: And what does that mean? I don't get what you mean by "returned"?

Comment: Request comes from url/books/index.html not from url/index.html. I just want to ignore url parameters. And go to index.html from root path.